# regex to match page[0-9] and nothing before or after

Tags: asp.net, regex, c#-4.0

I have a regex but it's not quite working the way i want

```
page[0-9]*

/pages/search.aspx?pageno=3&pg=232323&hdhdhd/page73733/xyz
```

In the above example, the only thing I want to match is `page73733`. But my regex matches the page in `/pages` and it matches page in pageno=3

i also tried `page[0-9].*`, then it matches `page73733` but it also matches everything that comes after it so that it actually matches `page73733/xyz`

```
page[0-9].*[^a-zA-Z&?/=]
```

That seems to do what i want, but that also seems like a ugly way to do it. Plus if i had something like `/page123/xyz/page456` it'll match that whole string.

So is there a better way to do this? I want to match ONLY the string page when it is followed by any number of digits, and if anything comes after the digits it should stop.

Comment: As all the answers point out, you probably want to use `+` instead of `*`, but we also need to know more about what you want to achieve. Are you doing URL rewriting or matching? Would you like to get multiple matches or just the last one? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want one match - if the url legitimately has more then one match, it means something went wrong on my end as the url should only ever have one occurrence of page123. In any case, it looks like using + solved the problem for me. Thank you to everyone who provided answers. Would have marked them all as answers if i could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Just use + instead of * as that will force a match that has numbers after it.

Another way to type that expression would be

```
/page[0-9]+
```

note the / , this would be helpful because without it you might get a match with something like "notApage123"

Comment: Remember, `c#`, the guy is going to get confused by `c#` trying to escape `\d`

Answer (score 4):

`*` means 0 or more occurrences.  `+` means 1 or more occurrences.

`page[0-9]+` should work.

Comment: Sigh, you win by 3 seconds.  I bow to your typing abilities.

Answer (score 2):

```
page[0-9]*
```

Will match *page* followed by zero or more numbers.  What you want is:

```
page[0-9]+
```

Which will match *page* followed by *one or more* numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `page[0-9]*` will match `[0-9]` 0 or more times. `+` would match it 1 or more times, and `?` would match it 0 or 1 times. An equivalent method to `?+*` is as follows:

- `?={0,1}`
- `*={0,}`
- `+={1,}`

This may be helpful for if you wanted to match a date:`\\d{4}(-\\d{1,2}){2}` which would match `2013-5-31`

-

That said, the resulting Regex for your particular problem would be:

- `page\\d+`
- `page\\d{1,}`
- `page[0-9]+`
- or `page[0-9]{1,}`

In your example `"/page123/xyz/page456"` you may want to match all occurrences, so don't forget the `g` or `global` modifier.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you only need to add `$` to your original regex to specify that after `page` you want the string to end. So the regex would be

```
page[0-9]*$
```

Also, this will match strings that end in `page` too, if you want only strings that end in page followed by any number, use this regex

```
page[0-9]+$
```

Comment: @Isaac What do you mean it would match nothing? It wouldn't match anything that ends with something other than page[0-9]* (or with a plus), but would match a string that does end with this pattern and considering the OP wrote `and if anything comes after the digits it should stop.` I think this is exactly what he/she wants.

Comment: Eg:with string `.../page73733/xyz` the OP wants `page73733`. What the OP meant by stop was, only grab `page` and the following numbers `then stop`

Comment: I'm curious what is the wanted match for this example by OP `/page123/xyz/page456` then.

Comment: OP could implement the global modifier to match all occurrences

Comment: While this may be true, since there's and ASP.NET tag on the question and the OP wrote examples that look like URLs I am guessing he is doing URL rewriting in which case he would definitely not want to match multiple occurances. We need more info from OP to proceed, but as I've written quite a number of URL rewrites, I've learnt that putting `$` on the end is almost a requirement for URL rewriting.

Comment: Regardless, `page73733/xyz` will never fit `page[0-9]*$` unless the `page73733` part is at the very end of the URL, which in his first example it is not

Comment: It won't, but OP wasn't exactly clear on what he exactly wants to match. He may even not be able to use any of the mentioned regular expressions. Until we know more, we can't know that which is why I left him a comment to elaborate on his exact needs.

Comment: _In the above example, the only thing I want to match is_ `page73733` that's the question I answered

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. In my example I really just wanted to match the first occurrence, and nothing in between. If there's more then one match, it means the url is bugged since page123 should only ever show up once. I did try your regex example and it doesn't seem to work. At least not for my purposes. http://regexpal.com/ Test your regex on that site using the following line of test code /pages/search.aspx?pageno=3&pg=232323&hdhdhd/page73733/xyz/page38383 - it only matches at the very end, but page123 could appear anywhere in the string, not just the end.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Depending on other variations of your needs, which you know best, you might want to also add a match for a slash in front as Eton B. already suggested. In my answer I wanted to note the importance of such tokens because in URL rewriting, you often get problems with finding the match somewhere else so you should be as specific as possible.